# Targeting multiple checkboxes by "name" instead of by "id"

Tags: javascript, forms

I need to uncheck all checked checkboxes from a fieldset. I know how to manually do it with multiple `getElementById` methods, but I would like to use a single `getElementsByName`. How can I more concisely express the code below?

```
… else {
  document.getElementById("foo").checked = false
  document.getElementById("bar").checked = false
  document.getElementById("baz").checked = false
}
```

---

```
<fieldset>
  <input type=checkbox name=collection id=foo>
  <label for=foo>Foo</label>

  <input type=checkbox name=collection id=bar>
  <label for=bar>Bar</label>

  <input type=checkbox name=collection id=baz>
  <label for=baz>Baz</label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all checkboxes through [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), and use [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for change state of every checkbox in collection.

```js
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset > input[name="collection"]:checked');

  checkboxes.forEach(e => e.checked = false); // for example set other checked state.
});
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type=checkbox name=collection id=foo>
  <label for=foo>Foo</label>

  <input type=checkbox name=collection id=bar checked>
  <label for=bar>Bar</label>

  <input type=checkbox name=collection id=baz checked>
  <label for=baz>Baz</label>
</fieldset>

<button id="btn">Change state</button>
```

Comment: Your code toggles checked/unchecked. I would like to just uncheck all inputs that are checked.

Comment: @Boletrone i've updated my code sample. Try now, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` to get all elements with the desired `name` attribute in your form:

```
var elements = myForm.querySelectorAll('[name="collection"]');
```

and then iterate over the elements.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make function to keep your code clear and easy to manage:

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
function Check(val){
 Array.from(checkboxes, function(e){
  e.checked = val
 }) 
}
Check(true)
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type=checkbox name=collection id=foo>
  <label for=foo>Foo</label>

  <input type=checkbox name=collection id=bar>
  <label for=bar>Bar</label>

  <input type=checkbox name=collection id=baz>
  <label for=baz>Baz</label>
</fieldset>
```